# Pyspark Column Transformation: Calculate Percentage Change for Each Group in a Column

Tags: pyspark

I'm using Pyspark on my local machine.  I have a spark dataframe with 4.5 million rows and approximately 30,000 different stocks.  I need to calculate the percentage change for each stock over time.  I've already ran orderBy so that all the stocks are grouped together (as shown in the example below).

A simplified example dataframe is below.

```
df = spark.read.csv("stock_price.txt", header=True, inferSchema=True)
df.show()

**Company**     **Price**
Company_A         100
Company_A         103
Company_A         105
Company_A         107
Company_B          23
Company_B          25
Company_B          28
Company_B          30
```

My desired output would be something like this

```
**Company**     **Price**     **%_Change**
Company_A         100              0
Company_A         103              3%
Company_A         105              2%
Company_A         107              2%
Company_B          23              0
Company_B          25              9%
Company_B          28              12%
Company_B          30              7%
```

The trick (in my opinion) is setting up a code that can do two things:
1) identify each time a new stock is listed
2) start calculating percentage change on the second observation for that stock and continue calculating the percentage change until the last observation.  It needs to start on the second observation since there can't be a percentage change until the second observation occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using `window` operation, ideally you would have column with `id` or `timestamp` to sort. For the sake of example, I am using `company` as sorting key.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.read.csv("stock_price.txt", header=True, inferSchema=True)
price_window = Window.partitionBy("company").orderBy("company")
df = df.withColumn("prev_value", F.lag(df.price).over(price_window))
df = df.withColumn("diff", F.when(F.isnull(df.price - df.prev_value), 0).otherwise(df.price - df.prev_value))

+---------+-----+----------+----+
|  company|price|prev_value|diff|
+---------+-----+----------+----+
|Company_B|   23|      null|   0|
|Company_B|   25|        23|   2|
|Company_B|   28|        25|   3|
|Company_B|   30|        28|   2|
|Company_A|  100|      null|   0|
|Company_A|  103|       100|   3|
|Company_A|  105|       103|   2|
|Company_A|  107|       105|   2|
+---------+-----+----------+----+
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe [Windows](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.Window) are the way to go here

some imports

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag
```

partitionBy('Company') keeps our stocks together.  I'm ordering by Price here, but it will likely be whatever datetime you have

```
win = Window.partitionBy('Company').orderBy('Price')
```

Calc percentage changed with the help of `lag` which grabs the previous value in a window

```
df.withColumn('perc_change', (df.Price - lag(df['Price']).over(win))/100).show()

+---------+-----+-----------+
|  Company|Price|perc_change|
+---------+-----+-----------+
|Company_B|   23|       null|
|Company_B|   25|       0.02|
|Company_B|   28|       0.03|
|Company_B|   30|       0.02|
|Company_A|  100|       null|
|Company_A|  103|       0.03|
|Company_A|  105|       0.02|
|Company_A|  107|       0.02|
+---------+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: Sorry @Bob but I don't think the percentage change between 23 and 25 is 0.02 (2%). Good answer otherwise.

Comment: df = df.withColumn('perc_change', F.abs(F.round((df['Price']-F.lag(df['Price']))/df['Price'], 2)))