# How to understand `e:` and `columnsName` in spark error message when using window function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a very simple code like

```
val win = Window.partitionBy("app").orderBy("date")
val appSpendChange = appSpend
  .withColumn("prevSpend", lag(col("Spend")).over(win))
  .withColumn("spendChange", when(isnull($"Spend" - "prevSpend"), 0)
              .otherwise($"spend" - "prevSpend"))
display(appSpendChange)
```

This should work as I am referring a PySpark example from and change it to scala :[Pyspark Column Transformation: Calculate Percentage Change for Each Group in a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470314/pyspark-column-transformation-calculate-percentage-change-for-each-group-in-a-c)

However, I get this error:

```
error: overloaded method value lag with alternatives:
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset: Int,defaultValue: Any,ignoreNulls: Boolean)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset: Int,defaultValue: Any)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (columnName: String,offset: Int,defaultValue: Any)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (columnName: String,offset: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
     cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

  .withColumn("prevPctSpend", lag(col("pctCtvSpend")).over(win))
                          ^
```

How should I understand it? Especially the `e:` annotation? Thanks and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: You are missing second parameter to `lag()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand this error as following:

- there are 5 methods `lag` defined with following parameters and return type (`(<parameters>)<return>`:

  - `(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset: Int,defaultValue: Any,ignoreNulls: Boolean)org.apache.spark.sql.Column`
  - `(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset: Int,defaultValue: Any)org.apache.spark.sql.Column`
  - `(columnName: String,offset: Int,defaultValue: Any)org.apache.spark.sql.Column`
  - `(columnName: String,offset: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.Column`
  - `(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.Column`
- none of these possibilities can be applied with parameters of types `(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)` (the code you wrote)

In the end it means you called a method with missing or invalid parameters.

As @Dima said, you likely want to add a second parameter (`offset`) to your call to `lag`.